# Calling a generic method in .NET that matches multiple interfaces?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, generics, interface

I have an generic extension method that is made available if a control matches multiple interfaces.  I am able to call this method directly on a control that supports both interfaces...

```
Public Function DisplayValue(Of T As {IChoiceControl, IDataSourceControl})(ByVal vctl As T) As String
End Function

Dim pctl As CustomControl = ... //implements above interfaces
Dim pstrDisplayed As String = pctl.DisplayValue() // works
```

...but how do I cast an object that I determine to match both interfaces so that I can call the method?

```
Dim pobj As Object = ...
If TypeOf pobj Is IChoiceControl AndAlso TypeOf pobj Is IDataSourceControl Then
    pstrDisplayed = CType(pobj, ?).DisplayValue()
End If
```

EDIT:

Defining the compound interface (exactly as shown) works fine.  Thanks.

```
Public Interface IChoiceDataSourceControl
    Inherits IChoiceControl, IDataSourceControl 
End Interface

If TypeOf pobj Is IChoiceDataSourceControl Then
    pstrDisplayed = CType(pobj, IChoiceDataSourceControl).DisplayValue()
End If
```

Answer (score 2):

1. In C#, you could use `dynamic`, but you'd have to give up on user-friendly extension method *instance-like* call:

   ```
   MyExtensionClass.DisplayValue((dynamic)pobj)
   ```

   Unfortunately, there is no `dynamic` in VB.NET (unless you use `Option Strict Off`, which makes `Object` behave like `dynamic`).
2. You can create a wrapper:

   ```
   Class Wrapper
       Implements IChoiceControl
       Implements IDataSourceControl

       Private _choiceControl As IChoiceControl
       Private _dataSource As IDataSourceControl

       Public Sub New(obj As Object)
           _choiceControl = CType(obj, IChoiceControl)
           _dataSource = CType(obj, IDataSourceControl)
       End Sub

       '' Delegate all IChoiceControl methods to _choiceControl
       '' and IDataSourceControl methods to _dataSource
   End Class
   ```

   and use it:

   ```
   Dim both As New Both()
   Dim bothAsObject = CType(both, Object)
   Dim wrappedBothAsObject = New Wrapper(bothAsObject)
   wrappedBothAsObject.DisplayValue()
   ```
3. Or you can create another interface, which implements `IChoiceControl` and `IDataSourceControl`, implement it and use it as generic constraint for your extension method.

Comment: "Unfortunately, there is no `dynamic` in VB.NET" -- There is, isn't there? That's how `Object` works when you use `Option Strict Off`. `dynamic` brought it to C# when VB.NET had already had it for a long time. Or did C# add anything VB.NET lacked?

Comment: @hvd I've updated my answer. However, I would not advice anyone to turn `Option String Off` :)

Comment: Well, it can be turned off for a single module with a single method, so that the rest of the project can keep `Option Strict On`. Used like that, I've sometimes found it useful.

Answer (score 0):

It may be simpler to define an interface that inherits from both interfaces and make your extension method where clause refer to that:

```
Public Interface IChoosableDataSourceableThinger 
    Inherits IChoiceControl, IDataSourceControl 
    Public Function DisplayValue As String
End Interface
```

Extension:

```
Public Function DisplayValue(Of T As IChoosableDataSourceableThinger)(ByVal vctl As T) As String
```

Cast:

```
If TypeOf pobj Is IChoosableDataSourceableThinger Then
    pstrDisplayed = CType(pobj, IChoosableDataSourceableThinger).DisplayValue()
End If
```

Comment: But you have to make sure all classes which implement both interfaces, implement that `IChoosableDataSourceableThinger`. Otherwise, it won't work (it's not a duck typing).

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek I know - I also saw your answer covered that as I was posting mine so I upvoted yours.